# cqe->res is -EINVAL when using io_uring writev

Tags: c, linux, file, io, posix

I'm new to io_uring and learning io_uring. And I try to wrap around io_uring syscall like liburing for testing.

With IORING_SETUP_IOPOLL enabled and SQPOLL disabled, I submit a writev sqe with non-zero user_data, but the cqe->res is always -22(-EINVAL).

With both IORING_SETUP_IOPOLL and SQPOLL disabled, the cqe->res is always 0. Also, the cqe->user_data is 0 too.

I carefully checked each field of the sqe and other configurations, but failed to resolve this problem.

Here's my code, io_uring.c:

```c
#include "sys/socket.h"
#include "./io_uring.h"
#include "aio.h"
#include "sys/uio.h"
#include "sys/epoll.h"
#include "sys/eventfd.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "sys/stat.h"
#include "sys/ioctl.h"
#include "sys/syscall.h"
#include "sys/mman.h"
#include "linux/fs.h"
#include "fcntl.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "linux/io_uring.h"
#include <bits/time.h>
#include <bits/types/struct_iovec.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <zconf.h>
#include "errno.h"

#include "sys/time.h"

#define QUEUE_DEPTH 128
#define BLOCK_SZ    (256*1024)

#define read_barrier()  __asm__ __volatile__("":::"memory")
#define write_barrier() __asm__ __volatile__("":::"memory")

static int io_uring_setup(unsigned entries, struct io_uring_params *p)
{
    return (int) syscall(__NR_io_uring_setup, entries, p);
}
static int io_uring_enter(int ring_fd, unsigned int to_submit,
                          unsigned int min_complete, unsigned int flags)
{
    return (int) syscall(__NR_io_uring_enter, ring_fd, to_submit, min_complete,
                   flags, NULL, 0);
}

int iouring_setup(struct iouring *r, int io_poll) {
    struct sq_ring *sring = &r->sqring;
    struct cq_ring *cring = &r->cqring;
    struct io_uring_params p;
    void *sq_ptr, *cq_ptr;

    memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p));
    if (io_poll) {
        p.flags |= IORING_SETUP_IOPOLL;
    }
    r->fd = io_uring_setup(QUEUE_DEPTH, &p);
    if (r->fd < 0) {
        perror("io_uring_setup1");
        return 1;
    }
    /*
     * io_uring communication happens via 2 shared kernel-user space ring buffers,
     * which can be jointly mapped with a single mmap() call in recent kernels. 
     * While the completion queue is directly manipulated, the submission queue 
     * has an indirection array in between. We map that in as well.
     * */
    int sring_sz = p.sq_off.array + p.sq_entries * sizeof(unsigned);
    int cring_sz = p.cq_off.cqes + p.cq_entries * sizeof(struct io_uring_cqe);
    /* In kernel version 5.4 and above, it is possible to map the submission and 
     * completion buffers with a single mmap() call. Rather than check for kernel 
     * versions, the recommended way is to just check the features field of the 
     * io_uring_params structure, which is a bit mask. If the 
     * IORING_FEAT_SINGLE_MMAP is set, then we can do away with the second mmap()
     * call to map the completion ring.
     * */
    if (p.features & IORING_FEAT_SINGLE_MMAP) {
        if (cring_sz > sring_sz) {
            sring_sz = cring_sz;
        }
        cring_sz = sring_sz;
    }
    /* Map in the submission and completion queue ring buffers.
     * Older kernels only map in the submission queue, though.
     * */
    sq_ptr = mmap(0, sring_sz, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
            MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE,
            r->fd, IORING_OFF_SQ_RING);
    if (sq_ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }
    if (p.features & IORING_FEAT_SINGLE_MMAP) {
        cq_ptr = sq_ptr;
    } else {
        /* Map in the completion queue ring buffer in older kernels separately */
        cq_ptr = mmap(0, cring_sz, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE,
                r->fd, IORING_OFF_CQ_RING);
        if (cq_ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
            perror("mmap");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    /* Save useful fields in a global app_io_sq_ring struct for later
     * easy reference */
    sring->khead = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.head;
    sring->ktail = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.tail;
    sring->ring_mask = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.ring_mask;
    sring->ring_entries = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.ring_entries;
    sring->flags = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.flags;
    sring->array = sq_ptr + p.sq_off.array;
    sring->head = *sring->khead;
    sring->tail = *sring->ktail;
    /* Map in the submission queue entries array */
    r->sqring.sqes = mmap(0, p.sq_entries * sizeof(struct io_uring_sqe),
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE,
            r->fd, IORING_OFF_SQES);
    if (sring->sqes == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }
    /* Save useful fields in a global app_io_cq_ring struct for later
     * easy reference */
    cring->khead = cq_ptr + p.cq_off.head;
    cring->ktail = cq_ptr + p.cq_off.tail;
    cring->ring_mask = cq_ptr + p.cq_off.ring_mask;
    cring->ring_entries = cq_ptr + p.cq_off.ring_entries;
    cring->cqes = cq_ptr + p.cq_off.cqes;
    r->flags = p.flags;
    r->sq = sq_ptr;
    r->cq = cq_ptr;
    return 0;
}


struct io_uring_sqe* iouring_get_sqe(struct iouring* ring) {
    uint32_t tail, head, entries, mask;
    tail = ring->sqring.tail + 1;
    head = __atomic_load_n(ring->sqring.khead, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
    entries = __atomic_load_n(ring->sqring.ring_entries, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
    mask = __atomic_load_n(ring->sqring.ring_mask, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
    printf("head=%d, tail=%d, idx=%d\n", head, tail, tail&mask);
    if (tail - head <= entries) {
        struct io_uring_sqe *sqe;
        sqe = &ring->sqring.sqes[tail & mask];
        ring->sqring.tail = tail;
        return sqe;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void iouring_sqe_iov(int opcode, struct io_uring_sqe* sqe, int fd, void* buf, size_t len, off_t off, uint64_t udata) {
    sqe->opcode = opcode;
    sqe->len = len;
    sqe->flags = 0;
    sqe->ioprio = 0;
    sqe->fd = fd;
    sqe->off = off;
    sqe->addr = (uint64_t) buf;
    sqe->rw_flags = 0;
    sqe->buf_index = 0;
    sqe->user_data = udata;
}

void iouring_sqe_writev(struct io_uring_sqe* sqe, int fd, struct iovec* vecs, size_t nr_vecs, off_t off) {
    iouring_sqe_iov(IORING_OP_WRITEV, sqe, fd, vecs, nr_vecs, off, 0);
}

/*
 * submit sqes and wait for min_complete events to complete.
*/
int iouring_submit_and_wait(struct iouring* ring, uint32_t min_complete) {
    uint32_t tail = ring->sqring.tail;
    uint32_t to_submit, flags = 0;
    uint32_t trap = 0;
    to_submit = tail - ring->sqring.head;

    if (to_submit) {
        ring->sqring.head = tail;
        __atomic_store_n(ring->sqring.ktail, tail, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);   // use fence?
        to_submit = tail - __atomic_load_n(ring->sqring.khead, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
    }

    if (!(ring->flags & IORING_SETUP_SQPOLL)) {
        /*
         * need to notify kernel
        */
        if (to_submit) trap = 1;
    } else if ((*ring->sqring.flags & IORING_SQ_NEED_WAKEUP)) {
        flags |= IORING_ENTER_SQ_WAKEUP;
        trap = 1;
    }
    
    if(min_complete > 0) {
        trap = 1;
        flags |= IORING_ENTER_GETEVENTS;
    } else if((ring->flags & IORING_SETUP_IOPOLL)) {
        flags |= IORING_ENTER_GETEVENTS;
    }

    if (!trap) {
        fprintf(stderr, "no trap: %d, %d\n", to_submit, min_complete);
        return to_submit;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "trap: %d, %d\n", to_submit, min_complete);

    // if (min_complete > 0) {
    //     flags |= IORING_ENTER_GETEVENTS;
    // }

    printf("enter (%d) (%u) (%u) (%u)\n", (*ring->sqring.ktail) - (*ring->sqring.khead), to_submit, flags, (*ring->cqring.ktail) - (*ring->cqring.khead));
    return io_uring_enter(ring->fd, to_submit, min_complete, flags);
}

int iouring_submit(struct iouring* ring) {
    return iouring_submit_and_wait(ring, 0);
}

int iouring_wait(struct iouring* ring, uint32_t min_complete) {
    return iouring_submit_and_wait(ring, min_complete);
}

int iouring_peek_cqe(struct iouring* ring, struct io_uring_cqe** cqe_ptr, uint32_t* available) {
    struct io_uring_cqe* cqe = NULL;
    uint32_t head, tail, n;
    *available = 0;
    
    head = __atomic_load_n(ring->cqring.khead, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
    tail = __atomic_load_n(ring->cqring.ktail, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);

    n = tail - head;
    printf("%s: n=%d\n", __func__, n);

    if (n) {
        cqe = &ring->cqring.cqes[head & (*ring->cqring.ring_mask)];
    }

    *cqe_ptr = cqe;
    *available = n;
    return 0;
}

int iouring_wait_cqe_n(struct iouring* ring, struct io_uring_cqe** cqe_ptr, uint32_t min_complete) {
    int ret = 0;
    struct io_uring_cqe* cqe;
    uint32_t available = 0;

    while (1) {
        ret = iouring_peek_cqe(ring, &cqe, &available);
        if (min_complete > available) {
            ret = iouring_submit_and_wait(ring, min_complete);
        }
        if (cqe) {
            break;
        }
        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("iouring_wait_cqe");
        }
    }

    *cqe_ptr = cqe;
    return ret;
}

void iouring_cqe_seen(struct iouring* ring, struct io_uring_cqe* cqe) {
    if (cqe) {
        __atomic_add_fetch(ring->cqring.khead, 1, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
    }
}

int iouring_wait_cqe(struct iouring* ring, struct io_uring_cqe** cqe_ptr) {
    return iouring_wait_cqe_n(ring, cqe_ptr, 1);
}


int main(){
    int fd;
    int res;
    struct iouring ring;

    iouring_setup(&ring, 1);

    fd = open("./test.data", O_DIRECT | O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0655);
    if (fd<=0) {
        printf("error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct iovec v;
    v.iov_len = 8192;
    posix_memalign(&v.iov_base, v.iov_len, v.iov_len);

    // res = pwritev(fd, &v, 1, 0);
    // if (res != v.iov_len) {
        // printf("error pwritev: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    // }

    struct io_uring_sqe* sqe = iouring_get_sqe(&ring);
    iouring_sqe_writev(sqe, fd, &v, 1, 0);
    sqe->user_data = fd;
    printf("%d, %d, %llx(%p), %d, %llu, %llu\n", sqe->opcode, sqe->fd, sqe->addr, &v, sqe->len, sqe->off, sqe->user_data);
    printf("submitted:%d\n", iouring_submit(&ring));
    printf("%d, %d, %llx(%p), %d, %llu, %llu\n", sqe->opcode, sqe->fd, sqe->addr, &v, sqe->len, sqe->off, sqe->user_data);

    struct io_uring_cqe *cqe;
    int ret = iouring_wait_cqe(&ring, &cqe);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("io_uring_wait_cqe");
        return 1;
    }
    if (cqe->res < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d Async writev failed %s.\n", cqe->user_data, strerror(cqe->res));
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", cqe->res, cqe->user_data);
    return 0;
}
```

The opcode (IORING_OP_WRITEV, 0x02) is existing, and the iov_base is aligned with block size.

My code doesn't work on both kernel5.4 and kernel5.15.

I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Try set all the fields in `iouring_sqe_iov()` that liburing `io_uring_prep_rw()` sets if you haven't tried already (`personality`, `file_index`, `addr3` and `__pad2`).  `writev()` says only overflow of sum of lengths or invalid count of vectors would cause that `errno`.

Comment: `iouring_get_sqe()` looks different particular `sqe = &ring->sqring.sqes[tail & mask];` where liburing does `sqe = &sq->sqes[(sq->sqe_tail & sq->ring_mask) << shift];` and your `tail` is `ring->sqring.tail + 1;` so different values.

Comment: If it was me I would replace liburing piece by piece with your own code.